# title in field group kendo ui grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

how can I give a title to a grouped field without showing it as a grid column? I am giving it a title in the grouped congiracion but it does not recognize it and it continues showing how the field is. I want the title to be DOCUMENTO and not balance as tipo_documento  the same way with two other fields grouped

```
 group: [
            {field: "tipo_documento",title:"Documento"},
            {field:"anio"},
            {field:"equipo"}
        ],
```

fields of grid

```
{
       field: "fecha_vigencia_ini", title: "FECHA VIGENCIA INICIO", 
      attributes: {
            "class": "font-grid"}
    },
    {
        field: "fecha_vigencia_fin", title: "FECHA VIGENCIA FIN", 
         attributes: {
            "class": "font-grid"}
    },
    {
        field: "descripcion",title: "DESCRIPCION" ,attributes: {
         "class": "font-grid"}
     },
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for groupHeaderTemplate https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

Comment: group: [
            {groupHeaderTemplate:"DOCUMENTO",field: "tipo_documento"},
            {groupHeaderTemplate:"AÑO",field:"anio"},
            {groupHeaderTemplate:"EQUIPO",field:"equipo"}
        ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved by adding `hidden:true`

```
{
 field: "tipo_documento",title: "DOCUMENTO" ,hidden:true
}
```